# Using a usb webcam as the source for the emulated camera device on the android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera

This seems to have been asked many times in the past; when using a webcam was not supported by the emulator and instead a checker-box image was shown.  Today the emulator does support using the webcam on the host system.  I cannot find any documentation on it, except for people saying it just works automatically.

The following link is for the developer docs.  It states that a webcam on the host device is supported, but doesn't give any instructions.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html

I am using SDK 17 on a Windows 7 (x64) machine.  My virtual device is Google APIs (API Level 10).  When I use the camera app, the preview is just a solid white image, and when I take a picture, i just get a sample image with the android logo.  My webcam is plugged in and working, but the AVD does not activate it.

Is there any documentation on getting the camera working?

I actually don't need the web-cam to work.  If I could simply supply an image file to be used instead of the android logo, that would be enough for me to test my app with.

**UPDATE**

Rebooted my desktop and now my camera is activated when the AVD is launched, but still get the same results in the emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works on the Ice Cream Sandwich emulator.  This feature is simply not available on earlier versions.